# Regarding On Prem to Cloud Migration

Tags: migration, cloud, repository, devops, azure-migrate

In Azure Migrate, we have the option to replicate the physical servers as a VM in Azure.

But that will replicate/migrate all the repositories from the physical server to Azure VM.

How can we filter out the repositories and migrate only those that are required from physical to Azure VM ?

One of the methods involve cloning the repo, downloading the same repo as a zip and then uploading it to another cloud only to be called cloned to the zip folder.

I am trying to reduce this manual method and want an automated solution, hence tried Azure Migrate. But need the option or way to not migrate all the repos.

Answer (score 0):

Azure Migrate does not provide a way to filter out specific repositories from a physical server when replicating it to an Azure VM.

One option is to use Git to clone the repositories from the physical server to a local machine, and then push the repositories to a Git repository hosted in Azure DevOps or GitHub. Once the repositories are in the cloud, you can use Azure DevOps or GitHub Actions to automate the deployment of the repositories to an Azure VM.